# Change the caption color of a groupbox but not the text in the groupbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I have a groupbox on my winform and I'd like to change the color of the caption / title but not use `ForeColor` as I don't want the text in the groupbox to change.

[image]

Comment: You'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941492/change-group-box-text-color (not the accepted from J.Skeet)

Comment: Just to clarity: Tim points to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7493900/993547, which is not the best workaround I believe.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks Tim that does work but not as well as Patrick's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `RadioButton` in another `Panel` which you `Dock` `Fill` in the `GroupBox`. Then set the `ForeColor` of that `Panel` to [`SystemColors.ControlText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.controltext(v=vs.110).aspx).

This prevents the `ForeColor` of the `RadioButton` to be derived from the `GroupBox`.